# update_attributes the data in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am working on ruby on rails , I am trying to update my data

```
def update
     @post = Post.find(params[:id])

     if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
         redirect_to post_path,:notice =>"post has been updated"
     else
         render "edit"
     end
 end
```

it's not updating and the error coming is :-

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in PostsController#update

Help me !

Comment: the code sample you posted is incomplete. post controller action method

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. normally in your controller you'll have something where you `permit` and `require` a set of attributes... instead of just passing through the `params[:post]` do you have that? Also - do you have any `attr_accessible` in your model? Can you please edit your question and put the answers there (code formatting in comments is dreadful)

Comment: Also: here is the Rails Guide on how to make your parameters "strong" (ie protect against attributes you don't want changed): http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters (because we don't use `attr_accessible` anymore)

Comment: Thankyou for your response. Yes, I had to make my paramaters strong

Comment: def posting 
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :category_id, :author_id)
    end    (all this is inside model)
This is the format for it ,Now can u guide me how to update my content .Ruby on rails 4.2.6

Answer (score 4):

You cannot just update values based on params[:post], you will have to whitelist them using strong params.

Basically white post params like this in the controller

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description)
end
```

And then in the controller

```
  def update
     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
         redirect_to post_path,:notice =>"post has been updated"
     else
         render "edit"
     end
  end
  private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description)
  end
```

Comment: Both the code snippets go inside controller, right?

Comment: Thankyou for you comment. While I am using your idea it is showing the error :-
undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass

Comment: `Post.find` doesn't return `nil` but raises an exception. @SIDDHARTHJAIN, how do you fetch `Post` from the database? You don't use `Post.find`, do you?

Comment: If you want `nil` instead of `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` use something like `Post.find_by(id: params[:id])`. Also, this answer by @Saad should be selected as it's correct.